# Force from Water Entering a Pressurized Tank with No Relief Valve

Tags: forces, fluid-dynamics

I am trying to understand how a force at the opposite wall from water entering a pressurized air tank (atmospheric pressure) with no relief valve to displace the compressed air can be deduced. I have created a simple illustration and believe this is similar to a failed air relief valve for a water lock in a submarine or other submerged vehicle. I think an approximate force from the water could be expressed using the jet discharge propulsion equation:

$$F= 2A\left( P_{depth} - P_{atm} \right)$$

However, I do not understand how to include compressed air into this equation? Any insight provided is much appreciated!

---

[image]

Comment: The system in the picture would lose all air very quickly, because pressure is not the same across the opening. It takes a very small pressure variation to disturb the mechanical equilibrium and most air would go out. This would be a complicated process which can't easily be analyzed otherwise than with a many-element computer simulation.

Comment: The argument you want to make would work for opening on the bottom side, because then the liquid pressure variation across the opening is much smaller and can be mitigated by surface effects.